# Return a success message on posting data to parse in iOS

Tags: javascript, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm using parse for my iOS app and I want parse to return a success message to my app after the user's post gets saved in parse.com. I am pretty much new to parse please someone help me out.

my iOS code

```
// Posting to Cloud...
PFObject *TrafficObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"TrafficClass"];
TrafficObject[@"Status"] = @"Traffic";
TrafficObject[@"Time"] = [self GetTime];
[TrafficObject saveInBackground];
```

parse side js code

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave('TrafficClass', function(request, response) {
response.success("Posted Successfully");
```

});

Comment: yes just hold on a second I 'll edit my question with the code

Comment: The above code which you trying is block based, you can also try with callbacks type. Which gives you success or error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[TrafficObject saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // notify user of success
    }
    else {
        // notify user of failure
    }
}];
```

No need to use a cloud code for this.  Save your api calls.